# How does Stata calculate the "predict varname, u" after xtreg random-effect?

Tags: r, stata, random-effects-model

What "predict varname, u" after xtreg with random-effects really do in Stata? How it works? I mean, how the ("individual") random-error component u_i is extracted from the overall e_it error component?

Is there a way doing this in R?

Comment: Welcome to the site! For `R`, you can use `ranef()` in the `lme4` package. `Stata` and `R` seem to both calculate empirical Bayes estimates of random effects.

Comment: For R's `plm` package, there is the function `ranef()` in it's development version. This should be the equivalent to Stata's `predict ..., u` after `xtreg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me expand my comment above. Assume your mixed-effects model is $$\boldsymbol y_i = \boldsymbol X_i \boldsymbol \beta + \boldsymbol Z_i \boldsymbol b_i + \boldsymbol \epsilon_i,$$ where $i$ denotes cluster $i$, random effects $\boldsymbol b_i \sim N(0,\boldsymbol D)$. Without loss of generality, assume $\boldsymbol \epsilon_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2 \boldsymbol I)$. Then the formula to calculate random effects is $$\hat{\boldsymbol b}_i=(\boldsymbol Z_i'\boldsymbol Z_i+\sigma^2 \boldsymbol D^{-1})^{-1}\boldsymbol Z_i'(\boldsymbol y_i - \boldsymbol X_i \boldsymbol \beta),$$ which can be generalized if you have a more general structure for $\mathrm{var}(\boldsymbol \epsilon_i).$

As far as I know, we can think the estimate $\hat{\boldsymbol b}_i$ in at least three ways:

- the best linear unbiased prediction ([BLUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_linear_unbiased_prediction)).
- the conditional mean/mode of $\boldsymbol b_i | \boldsymbol
     y_i$. If we use EM algorithm for the estimation, we will see the
  above formula in the E step.
- the [empirical Bayes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_Bayes_method) estimator, since we do not specify a prior for $\boldsymbol b_i$ as in full Bayesian analysis. In some areas, it is also called "expected a posteriori".

Comment: Thank you Randel! That was what I was asking for. The general references in microeconometrics literature (Wooldridge and Cameron/Triverdi) don't get so far. Trying use yor notation, I could reproduce the Stata's output using the plm function in R in this way: ${b}_i=c_i(\overline{y}_i-\overline{x}'_i\widehat{\beta}_{RE})$, where $c_i=\frac{\widehat{\sigma_b}}{\widehat{\sigma_b^2}+(\widehat{\sigma}_{\epsilon}/T_i)}$, and where $T_i$ is the number of times the individual appears (times, waves...). So, I ask you, what/how is matrix $D$ estimated?

Comment: @Rodrigo Great. You should estimate $D$ using an iterative algorithm, say, EM algorithm. An explicit procedure is on Page 9 of [this excellent paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11749-009-0138-x).